# Probability that the function returns a specific value

Tags: python, sum, probability

I am having trouble understanding a way to find a mathematical expression for the following probability values that are requested.  I was given a Python function, defined as:

```py
def randomFunction(n):
    return sum([random.choice([-1,1] for _ in range(n)])
```

It is then requested to find to find the probability values that:

1. randomFunction(25) will return 4
2. randomFunction(25) will return 3
3. randomFunction(6000) will return 0 (accurate "analytic estimate," not based on simulation results)

I created a monte carlo simulation for all three probabilities in order to be able to double check my work; however, I am unsure of how to tackle this problem mathematically.

I imagine that the third question will require Stirling's approximation, due to it being worded as an "analytic estimate."  I think the disconnect is occurring with how I find the number of successes in order to determine the probability.  Lastly, I was able to solve the first one, through reasoning, that it would be a probability of 0.0, due to the fact that an even number cannot be sum when adding and/or subtracting by ±1 for an odd amount of times.

I feel like this is a very elementary problem; however, I seem to missing how to approach the question.  Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated!

My simulation is below, in case anyone was interested:

```
import random

# Initialize Counters
count4 = 0
count3 = 0
count0 = 0

# Function that 
def randomFunction(n):
    return sum([random.choice([-1,1]) for _ in range(n)])

### Simulation for Sum 4 ###
for x in range(10**4):
    if randomFunction(25) == 4:
        count4 += 1

print "Sum 4 Count: ",count4
print "P(Sum 4): ",float(count4)/10**4
############################

### Simulation for Sum 3 ###
for x in range(10**4):
    if randomFunction(25) == 3:
        count3+=1

print "Sum 3 Count: ",count3
print "P(Sum 3): ",float(count3)/10**4
############################

### Simulation for Sum 0 ###
for x in range(10**4):
    if randomFunction(6000) == 0:
        count0+=1
    if x%1000==0: # Progress update every 10%
        print str((float(x)/10**4)*100)+"%"

print "Sum 0 Count: ",count0
print "P(Sum 0): ",float(count0)/10**4
############################
```

Comment: `randomFunction` will always raise a SyntaxError, as there are unbalanced parentheses. Therefore, all your probabilities reduce to 0

Comment: I bet the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) has something to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) In order for `randomFunction(25)` to return 4, it has to generate four `1`s aside from equal numbers of `1`s and `-1`s.

If it's going to generate 25 numbers in total, then it'll need to get equal numbers of `1`s and `-1`s out of 25-4=21 remaining numbers. This is mathematically impossible. Therefore, the answer is this is 0

(2) Let's use the same logic: you'll need fourteen `1`s and eleven `-1`s. Now, there are `2^25` possible ways of generating a list of 25 `1`s and `-1`s in `randomFunction`; and you need 11 of those 25 to be a specific number (though it doesn't really matter which 11 numbers). There are therefore `25choose11` ways of getting these 11 numbers. Super! So now, all you need to compute is `25choose11 / 2^25`

(3) Same logic as before: you now need 3000 `1`s and `3000` `-1`s. So, compute `6000choose3000 / 2^6000`